# Where is header('location:url') redirect takes place?

Tags: php, http-headers

If I have the following code, the browser will take this to the specified location.

```
<script>window.location = "https://google.com";</script>
```

But what happens when `header('location:$url');` is used. Does the browser receive the headers and makes the redirection from client side ?

Comment: Yes, It redirects from a client side

Comment: header('location:$url')  <-- will not work unless you use `"`, `header` is a function in php used for redirection from server side.

Comment: header() is a php function so its executed on the server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how and when you want to redirect the user to another page.

If you want to instantly redirect a user to another page without him seeing anything of a site in between, you should use the PHP header redirect method.

If you have a Javascript and some action of the user has to result in him entering another page, that is when you should use window.location.

The meta tag refresh is often used on download sites whenever you see these "Your download should start automatically" messages. You can let the user load a page, wait for a certain amount of time, then redirect him (e.g. to a to-be-downloaded file) without Javascript.

The browser will process the header redirect right away, whereas the Javascript redirect will not be executed until the page has loaded (or at least enough of it to run the Javascript). Also, it will be the Javascript engine executing the redirect instead of the browser itself.

Doing it via the header will perform better. (slightly anyway...)

Comment: Is there documentation that mention the same (header) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>window.location = "https://google.com";</script>
```

This is how a user is redirected to a site using JS. This is done on client side.

`header` is a function in PHP, you can redirect user based on your logic from server side to a new url.

Answer (score 0):

When you put this code into your code
`<script>window.location = "https://google.com";</script>`

 It will being send to client's browser, then when the DOM was fully loaded it will being executed by browser and redirect to google.com
But when you put `header('location:$url');` to your php code. The server will send 302 Response to redirect client browser to the new URL directly without being executed by javascript..